# scandir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path

Tags: php

Hi I am new to php since i don't know much to solve the warning I am getting while I try to fetch the names of the file in my folder.

Warning: scandir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path.

But while uploading file i have used the same path;
Path is:store_documents/

Here goes my very simple code:

```
$dir=opendir("store_documents/");
$read_file=scandir($dir);
echo $read_file;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
$dir    = 'store_documents';
$files = scandir($dir);
print_r($files);
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
$dir="store_documents";
$read_file=@scandir($dir);
echo $read_file;
?>
```

@ will remove the warning **or** try `error_reporting(0);`(you don't need both)

Comment: why both? any one is suffice

Comment: had just given example to do both